# File in use error C# reading text from user specified file

Tags: c#, stream, runtime-error

My code is giving a runtime error that the file is in use already. I am not sure how I work around this. I need the file dialog to interact with the user but I want read through it line by line. the file is semicolon delimited and I parse it manually and feed it into the system. How can I release the file from opendialog so I can work with it. Any help much appreciated thanks in advance.

```
List<string> datalinestream = new List<string>();
FileDialog FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();

if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{


    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(FD.FileName);
    using (reader)
    {
        string line = "";
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            while (!string.Equals(reader.Read(),"/r"))
            {
                datalinestream.Add(GetWord(reader));
            }
            LuceneDB.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new MATS_Doc( datalinestream));
            datalinestream.Clear();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change `using` block -> `using(TextReader reader = new StreamReader(FD.FileName){...}`

Comment: @IAbstract: That's essentially the same thing. Both are completely valid

Comment: @BryanJ.Ross: essentially the same in that both will compile, and `reader` may dispose ... but `reader` is still in scope and can easily be called or - worse - passed through a series of methods that make finding a bug difficult.

Comment: All true, except that `reader` _will_ dispose. `Dispose` isn't necessary if the constructor throws, and the next line is `using`. But that isn't the source of the OP's error. Unless there's more to this that he hasn't posted.

Comment: There was more to it. I had the file I was reading open. It was minimized in a text editor so I could not see it hence the call. Thank you for the prompt responses!

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is I will create a temporary file that contains the same information of the original text file. I will make sure to format the filename with something like a GUID so it will not cause any issues again. My code then will do all of the work on the temporary file.

Afterwards, (if you need to) update the original file with the changes that you did on the temporary file.

Working with files sometimes is a headache but workarounds or tricking the system does the job.

Comment: issue was on my end but voted since you put forth the effort to try and fix and your code was a bit neater allready has a catch for a failed user dialog. That is why I am the Code Novice.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest separating out the `FileOpenDialog` interaction from the parsing.

Something like this:

```
List<string> datalinestream = new List<string>();
string fileName;

using(FileDialog FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog())
{
    if(FD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        fileName = FD.FileName;
    else
        return;
}

TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
using (reader)
{
    string line = "";
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        while (reader.Read() != '\r')
        {
            datalinestream.Add(GetWord(reader));
        }
        LuceneDB.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new MATS_Doc( datalinestream));
        datalinestream.Clear();
    }
}
```

I'm also assuming that you want to check for a `\r` character, instead of a string with the two characters `/` and `r`, as `StreamReader.Read()` returns a single character, otherwise your inner loop will have to change pretty drastically.

Comment: issue was on my end but voted since you put forth the effort to try and fix and your code was a bit neater allready has a catch for a failed user dialog. That is why I am the Code Novice.Thanks!!! –